# AndroidX: 'com.google.android.material:material*' library is calling androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 but this does not download

Tags: android, androidx

I'll try to explain at detail what's happening.

***Gradle version: 5.1.1.

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 3.4.0**

This is my Project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my App build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidxexamp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

}
```

**What's happening?**

The library 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04' tries to download the androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 dependency. But this does not download:

Label: "Could not find cardview.aar (androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar"

The point is: When I manually try to download from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar it perfectly downloads. But the IDE cannot.

So, I'm tried to manually insert the androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 library. I donwloaded the cardview-1.0.0.aar file and successfully inserted to A.Studio.

But I need the material library in order to use TabLayout. So, when I include (implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04') this fails againg saying it cannot resolve at https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar.

I'm trying to see if there is any chance to avoid that the material library stop calling out the cardview dependency, don't know if possible.

Also, if I insert ( implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0') A Studio says cannot resolve this link.

Please, any advice? Thanks very much

Comment: You are using an alpha version of material. Try using the most recent stable version instead and see if it works.

Comment: Also make sure your Gradle is not working offline.

Comment: Hi, thanks. @Code-Apprentice, I tried with the official verison of com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' and '1.1.0' but still says "cannot resolve from "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/cardview/cardview/1.0.0/cardview-1.0.0.aar."

Comment: Hi @harrytmthy, thanks, Gradle is working online, the point is if I comment the line: "implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0" then builds OK.  Also like I said, I can manually donwload the cardview dependecy from such link, I figure out why the IDE cannot   :-(

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it working now. I upgraded the Gradle version from 5.1.1 to 6.1.1, after that, it could resolved the dependency. Thank you.